# IE8 bug - document width keeps increasing on adding dynamic images?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I have a html like this, a DIV box containing image. DIV is initially hidden with display:none

```
<div class="hide">
   <div>some text</div>
   <img src=""/>
   <div> some text</div>
</div>
```

On some event I am generating a image at runtime on server and assigning the url to the img src attribute using Jquery

```
$('div').removeClass('hide');
$('div img').attr('src','url on server');
```

I noticed that as soon as the image is loaded, the horizontal scrollbar starts shrinking. i.e. the document keep adding space on the right side.

I have tried various solutions and found that if I don't hide the DIV box initially and specify a height and width to image, then the scrollbar doesn't shrink. It makes me think that IE8 is having trouble calculating width when adding new image dynamically. Another reason may be my page is quite complex html and perhaps IE8 is not able to handle the html.

This doesn't happen in FireFox 7.0

Comment: Your selectors are wrong, a typo maybe? Do you have an example page somewhere?

Comment: corrected typo, here's JSBin http://jsbin.com/ohEQoy/1 this page doesn't have the problem stated, so most likely it's the composition of my html page that's causing trouble.